# go-swagger not generating model info

Tags: go, swagger-2.0

Here is my simple rest service:

```
// Package classification User API.
//
// the purpose of this application is to provide an application
// that is using plain go code to define an API
//
// This should demonstrate all the possible comment annotations
// that are available to turn go code into a fully compliant swagger 2.0 spec
//
// Terms Of Service:
//
// there are no TOS at this moment, use at your own risk we take no responsibility
//
//     Schemes: http, https
//     Host: localhost
//     BasePath: /v2
//     Version: 0.0.1
//     License: MIT http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
//     Contact: John Doe<john.doe@example.com> http://john.doe.com
//
//     Consumes:
//     - application/json
//     - application/xml
//
//     Produces:
//     - application/json
//     - application/xml
//
//
// swagger:meta
package main
import (
 "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
 "strconv"
 "database/sql"
 _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
 "gopkg.in/gorp.v1"
 "log"
)

// swagger:model
// User represents the user for this application
//
// A user is the security principal for this application.
// It's also used as one of main axis for reporting.
//
// A user can have friends with whom they can share what they like.
//
type User struct {
    // the id for this user
    //
    // required: true
    // min: 1
    Id int64 `db:"id" json:"id"`
    // the first name for this user
    // required: true
    // min length: 3
    Firstname string `db:"firstname" json:"firstname"`
    // the last name for this user
    // required: true
    // min length: 3
    Lastname string `db:"lastname" json:"lastname"`
}

func main() {
 r := gin.Default()
 r.Use(Cors())
 v1 := r.Group("api/v1")
 {
 v1.GET("/users", GetUsers)
 v1.GET("/users/:id", GetUser)
 v1.POST("/users", PostUser)
 v1.PUT("/users/:id", UpdateUser)
 v1.DELETE("/users/:id", DeleteUser)
 v1.OPTIONS("/users", OptionsUser)     // POST
 v1.OPTIONS("/users/:id", OptionsUser) // PUT, DELETE
 }
r.Run(":8696")
}


func GetUsers(c *gin.Context) {
    // swagger:route GET /user listPets pets users
    //
    // Lists pets filtered by some parameters.
    //
    // This will show all available pets by default.
    // You can get the pets that are out of stock
    //
    //     Consumes:
    //     - application/json
    //     - application/x-protobuf
    //
    //     Produces:
    //     - application/json
    //     - application/x-protobuf
    //
    //     Schemes: http, https, ws, wss
    //
    //     Security:
    //       api_key:
    //       oauth: read, write
    //
    //     Responses:
    //       default: genericError
    //       200: someResponse
    //       422: validationError
     var users []User
     _, err := dbmap.Select(&users, "SELECT * FROM user")
    if err == nil {
     c.JSON(200, users)
     } else {
     c.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": "no user(s) into the table"})
 }
// curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users
}

func GetUser(c *gin.Context) {
 id := c.Params.ByName("id")
 var user User
 err := dbmap.SelectOne(&user, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?", id)
if err == nil {
 user_id, _ := strconv.ParseInt(id, 0, 64)
content := &User{
 Id: user_id,
 Firstname: user.Firstname,
 Lastname: user.Lastname,
 }
 c.JSON(200, content)
 } else {
 c.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": "user not found"})
 }
// curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1
}

func PostUser(c *gin.Context) {
 var user User
 c.Bind(&user)
if user.Firstname != "" && user.Lastname != "" {
if insert, _ := dbmap.Exec(`INSERT INTO user (firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?)`, user.Firstname, user.Lastname); insert != nil {
 user_id, err := insert.LastInsertId()
 if err == nil {
 content := &User{
 Id: user_id,
 Firstname: user.Firstname,
 Lastname: user.Lastname,
 }
 c.JSON(201, content)
 } else {
 checkErr(err, "Insert failed")
 }
 }
} else {
 c.JSON(422, gin.H{"error": "fields are empty"})
 }
// curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"firstname\": \"Thea\", \"lastname\": \"Queen\" }" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users
}

func UpdateUser(c *gin.Context) {
 id := c.Params.ByName("id")
 var user User
 err := dbmap.SelectOne(&user, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?", id)
if err == nil {
 var json User
 c.Bind(&json)
user_id, _ := strconv.ParseInt(id, 0, 64)
user := User{
 Id: user_id,
 Firstname: json.Firstname,
 Lastname: json.Lastname,
 }
if user.Firstname != "" && user.Lastname != ""{
 _, err = dbmap.Update(&user)
if err == nil {
 c.JSON(200, user)
 } else {
 checkErr(err, "Updated failed")
 }
} else {
 c.JSON(422, gin.H{"error": "fields are empty"})
 }
} else {
 c.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": "user not found"})
 }
// curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"firstname\": \"Thea\", \"lastname\": \"Merlyn\" }" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1
}

func DeleteUser(c *gin.Context) {
 id := c.Params.ByName("id")
var user User
 err := dbmap.SelectOne(&user, "SELECT id FROM user WHERE id=?", id)
if err == nil {
 _, err = dbmap.Delete(&user)
if err == nil {
 c.JSON(200, gin.H{"id #" + id: " deleted"})
 } else {
 checkErr(err, "Delete failed")
 }
} else {
 c.JSON(404, gin.H{"error": "user not found"})
 }
// curl -i -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/1
}

var dbmap = initDb()
func initDb() *gorp.DbMap {
 db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
        "root:max_123@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/gotest")
 checkErr(err, "sql.Open failed")
 dbmap := &gorp.DbMap{Db: db, Dialect:           gorp.MySQLDialect{"InnoDB", "UTF8"}}
 dbmap.AddTableWithName(User{}, "User").SetKeys(true, "Id")
 err = dbmap.CreateTablesIfNotExists()
 checkErr(err, "Create table failed")
return dbmap
}

func checkErr(err error, msg string) {
 if err != nil {
 log.Fatalln(msg, err)
 }
}


func Cors() gin.HandlerFunc {
 return func(c *gin.Context) {
 c.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
 c.Next()
 }
}

func OptionsUser(c *gin.Context) {
 c.Writer.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
 c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE,POST, PUT")
 c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
 c.Next()
}
```

Now when I'm executing :
swagger generate spec -o ./swagger.json
to generate the json spec I'm getting:

```
{
    "consumes": ["application/json", "application/xml"],
    "produces": ["application/json", "application/xml"],
    "schemes": ["http", "https"],
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "description": "the purpose of this application is to provide an application\nthat is using plain go code to define an API\n\nThis should demonstrate all the possible comment annotations\nthat are available to turn go code into a fully compliant swagger 2.0 spec",
        "title": "User API.",
        "termsOfService": "there are no TOS at this moment, use at your own risk we take no responsibility",
        "contact": {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "url": "http://john.doe.com",
            "email": "john.doe@example.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "MIT",
            "url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
        },
        "version": "0.0.1"
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "basePath": "/v2",
    "paths": {
        "/user": {
            "get": {
                "description": "This will show all available pets by default.\nYou can get the pets that are out of stock",
                "consumes": ["application/json", "application/x-protobuf"],
                "produces": ["application/json", "application/x-protobuf"],
                "schemes": ["http", "https", "ws", "wss"],
                "tags": ["listPets", "pets"],
                "summary": "Lists pets filtered by some parameters.",
                "operationId": "users",
                "security": [{
                    "api_key": null
                }, {
                    "oauth": ["read", "write"]
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "$ref": "#/responses/someResponse"
                    },
                    "422": {
                        "$ref": "#/responses/validationError"
                    },
                    "default": {
                        "$ref": "#/responses/genericError"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {}
}
```

Note that my definitions are empty, not sure why.
If I paste the same json spec in http://editor.swagger.io/#/
It says

```
Error
 Object
message:  "options.definition is required"
code:  "UNCAUGHT_SWAY_WORKER_ERROR"
```

Any directions on what is the right way to generate swagger documentation would help

Answer (score 2):

It's because go-swagger can't detect the usage of your definitions. I made the assumption that you'd always have a struct describing the parameters and that those would always use the definitions that are in use.
It would be great if you could submit this question as an issue on the repo with your sample program. I'll add it to my tests.

Comment: issue nbr #334 Thanks !